# Scraper works until uploaded to aws (except on .jp links)

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, cheerio

I have finished coding my web scraper and it works beautifully when running on a localhost server. It scrapes amazon links, and I had it idiot proofed to cover everything. Once I uploaded to aws i started getting 503 errors soon as i run it. At first I thought I pinged too many times so I tried amazon.jp and the scraping worked perfectly. Ran like a clock. After a lot of trial and error looking over my code I assumed my server's ip was the culprit. However running a brand new instance with a fresh IP made no difference. So I was stuck again. I tried for a bit looking into creating amazon api gateway to do the get request for the urls, but got stuck there too and went back to my original code again. I assumed at this point that the code running on my localhost express server would fail but for some reason it hasn't. This leaves me to believe it's something to do with how my aws is setup. I can safely say it has nothing to do with security groups. I setup initially with all ports open as an idiot proof test since my site hasn't officially launched yet.

I am currently using a basic ec2 instance running ubuntu with mongoDB, nodejs, express, cheerio, axios, and a handful of other node modules. I'll be honest AWS isn't my forte so I'm not quite sure where I should be looking. I am searching through threads while writing this, but haven't found anything that leaves me any clues. Linux and sysadmin stuff isn't my forte so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is _possible_ that the IP address range is blocked to prevent scraping. I would not encourage people to scrape websites in contravention of a site's Terms & Conditions. Amazon.com provides a Product API for requesting information. Anything beyond that API possibly isn't intended to be provided without violating their Terms.

Comment: try to access the same website's that you are trying to scrap using a `curl https://[website-iam-scraping.com]` see what you get. this will help you isolate the problem

Comment: ```[1]   Done                    curl https://www.amazon.com/Echo-Dot/dp/B07PDHSLM6/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=echo
    [2]-  Done                    qid=1575425978
    [3]+  Done                    smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER```


this is what i get along with a 503 redirect of the html. on amazon.jp I get this:
    ```[1] 8931
    [2] 8932
    [3] 8933
    [4] 8934
    [5] 8935```

Comment: That sounds right, I would expect they block their own datacenters, and probably competing ones too (Digital Ocean, etc..). You'll need residential ip's for this.

Comment: so why then are jp datacenters being let through?