# Error 503 Scraping Amazon Data from LightSail Instance

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to scrape price data from Amazon, but I keep running into a 503 error. I know you're probably supposed to use the Amazon API, but since I'm not a seller, it doesn't seem like the best option. The odd thing about this is that the test I wrote runs fine on my local computer, but when I run it off of the AWS LightSail instance, I keep getting a 503 Error. Any thoughts? Here's what I'm working with:

```
const headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
};
axios.get("https://www.amazon.com/LUMBERJACKED-Pre-Workout-Supplement-CarnoSyn-Servings/dp/B0839PB49F/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=lumberjacked&qid=1633477266&s=hpc&sr=1-4", {headers}).then((response) => {
  const dom = new JSDOM(response.data, {virtualConsole});
  const element = dom.window.document.querySelector("#priceblock_saleprice").textContent;
  var number = Number(element.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""))
  console.log(number);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Also, before I get this reported as a duplicate, the issue I am encountering is only on the Lightsail Instance. I have not seen any other questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it AWS might block their own IPs from scraping amazon.com:

[Scraper works until uploaded to aws (except on .jp links)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167609/scraper-works-until-uploaded-to-aws-except-on-jp-links)

I'm running into the same issue with AWS Batch using a fargate queue.